# How to define a function that returns an object with getter and setter based on string argument

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble finding the right typing for a function that generates an object with setter and getter properties. I think my best bet is some use of template string literals, but I am having a hard time finding the magic combination of types. In pseudo-code JS, what I would like is something like this:

```js
function createGetterAndSetter( key ) {
  return {
    [`get${capitalize(key)}`] : ( model ) => {
      return model[key]
    },
    [`set${capitalize(key)}`] : ( model, value ) => {
      return {
        ...model,
        [key] : value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what I've tried so far is this:

```
interface Model {
  [key:string]: any
}
type ModelKey = keyof Model & string
type Setter = ( model : Model, value : unknown ) => Model
type Getter = ( model : Model ) => unknown
type GetterKey<T extends string> = `get${Capitalize<T>}`
type SetterKey<T extends string> = `set${Capitalize<T>}`
type GetterSetterKeys<T extends string> = GetterKey<T> | SetterKey<T>
type GetterSetter<T extends GetterKey | SetterKey> = Record<GetterSetterKeys<T>, Getter | Setter>

function createGetterAndSetter<T extends ModelKey>( key : ModelKey ) : GetterSetter<T> {
  const keyName = `${key[0].toUpperCase() + key.substring( 1 )}`

  return {
    [`set${keyName}`] : createSetValue( key, setOpts ) as Setter,
    [`get${keyName}`] : createGetValue( key, getOpts ) as Getter
  } as GetterSetter<T>
}
```

I'm quite new to TS, so this is probably nonsensical in some respects, but it does seem get the compiler to recognize that the return of `createGetterAndSetter` is an object with getX and setX keys, it just can't recognize whether the value for those keys is a getter or setter... it only knows it's one of the union of the two.

It may help to know that I was inspired by the `createApi` function of redux-toolkit, which is able to [create named hooks](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview#create-an-api-slice) for you based on your named endpoints.

Comment: Are you asking for the typings only? Or the implementation as well?  Do you really want the gotten/set values to be of type `any`? There's no strong typing for values?

Comment: Like, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXQZ9N) might meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer explaining it.  If not, wham am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I appreciate the suggestion, but the key needs to be an arbitrary string and not based on a remapping of a known object's keys, like your Foo object. In the simplest form, given the string "cow", I'd like something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/EQYw9g7sAEC8B80AUBvAsAKGtA5gUwBcBhSaALmgFswATPAGzkWrvoG1RJgBdAGk2wBnQiQjlkVWg17QAbgEN6AVzzQAlE2Qpo4MRQXK8MgHSmWDaAF81ma0A)

Comment: Okay, but it still seems weird that you want a single string.  You're the boss, I guess.  Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wepJEW) work for you?  If so I can write up an answer, if not, what doesn't work about it?

Comment: @jcalz That's awesome! Exactly what I wanted and more. If you make it into an answer, I'll accept. I will also try to study this closely to figure out what the heck you did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible typing:

```
type GetterSetter<K extends string> =
  { [P in `get${Capitalize<K>}`]:
    <T extends { [Q in K]: any }>(model: T) => T[K]
  } &
  { [P in `set${Capitalize<K>}`]:
    <T extends { [Q in K]: any }>(model: T, value: T[K]) => T
  };
declare const getterSetter: <K extends string>(k: K) => GetterSetter<K>
```

So `getterSetter()` takes a `key` of generic type `K` and returns a value of type `GetterSetter<K>`.  This type uses [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to make the method names from `K`, and the method types are themselves generic so that the return type of `getXXX` and the `value` parameter of `setXXX` are strongly typed with respect to the type of the `model` parameter.

The implementation of `getterSetter` could be:

```
const capitalize = (k: string) => k[0].toUpperCase() + k.substring(1);
const getterSetter = <K extends string>(k: K) => ({
  [`get${capitalize(k)}`]: (m: any) => m[k],
  [`set${capitalize(k)}`]: (m: any, v: any) => ({ ...m, [k]: v })
}) as GetterSetter<K>;
```

Note that I used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (`as GetterSetter<K>`) as well as [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) inside the implementation.  That's because, while it's straightforward-ish to define the `GetterSetter<K>` typing, it's a lot trickier to get the compiler to verify that you've implemented it properly.  It would need to, among other things, understand that `captialize()` performs at a value level the same thing [the `Capitalize<T>` type function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#capitalizestringtype) performs at the type level.  And it would need to do better typing on computed properties (see [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948)), etc.  It's a lot easier to just use `any` and `as` and triple check that we didn't do anything wrong, than it is to overcome these hurdles.

Anyway, let's try it out:

```
const foo = {
  prop1: "hey",
  prop2: 123,
  prop3: true
}

const p1 = getterSetter("prop1");
console.log(p1.getProp1(foo).toUpperCase()); // HEY

p1.getProp1({a: 123}) // error! {a: 123} not expected since it doesn't have a prop1 key

console.log(p1.getProp1({prop1: Math.PI}).toFixed(2)) // 3.14

const bar = p1.setProp1(foo, "you");
console.log(bar.prop1.toUpperCase()) // YOU
```

Looks good.  The value `p1` is of type `GetterSetter<"prop1">` and therefore has a `getProp1()` and a `setProp1()` method, each of which behave well.  The compiler understands that `p1.getProp1({prop1: Math.PI})` is of type `number`, and that `p1.getProp1({a: 123})` is an error.  And the same with `setProp1()`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hzAgJwMr0UgPAaShAHogHYAmAzlGcEgJZEDmAfFALwCwAUFFAN5QDaABSh0oAA3rwAJDwDCAQzA1g8gDY0AXhByMAvmIC6ALk7dumACp5CEUhT78AiiKJRsxqPKIgouxgAoAWwB7EghVIygLAEpWZgt+d1NfKAAyZIdhUTEyaTlFZTVNbWw9QxMuM0trYnJeAWdRd0ivHz8g0PDIiwAaKAA3NQBXCG7Eg1iWeOTdAG5OAHoFqDCAY1V5JGhV4KIqKEkEZDQjpEicGts6qloGAIBrSOxJ5jhTk4wdTk4dveAoVYFFTqLSsKD+R6Uah0egvKD3fgABgMADpgMEAKpgSBIBS5fyxADU8JRZCGACMbjD-ABGaLzDi-faHDAfZBgi4EWoUKl3CFPOH+HjJfgSPKApTA4oQ6L6DxBFreOGBfj3Aw9EU5cVAopaGVyyIKzzePr9RUgQV8FHWwJ9VUefq+aKcXSxeQUN6s9DIHQMn67fYAM2CwTBwsqYCQwTANMiACIABYQEBxjURqNgABMkRpmYAzGnuJHo3nItQRi7voyA-8Y2CWcdvUh-HHizG4-T-XtgqoICjVMF6P4YyjDoIMzT-MHgtE0Zjscg8RACfSoEsoAAJACiAE0qyOxxOhZ4c-mnWvlsgo0gAIS8eSnvO6KBEYL-AiQVaIEiUOiraDKCswQQGQRAAOT-Am8j9NA8hQG2NLwsmVZMj2fYDkOB7wOO0aTnwCGRAAsvIwAJiiggAJJOnOABiND4BAJD+Jm0SxOueYojSAAsKE1lA5KbGCI65MAOExlOIZ9HGIDBEMHYMqhvb9oO-gCUgKIIXOWI4kuK4XlAO4APIYlWpkcEAA)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and especially for the explanation!